What does "feeling knuckles like walnuts in an empty leather glove clutch" mean?
I'm reading a book, The Clan Corporate: Book Three of The Merchant Princes by Charles Stross, that contains the following sentences:

And she [Angelin] walked at a painful shuffle. Miriam matched her speed, feeling knuckles like walnuts in an empty leather glove clutch at her arm. I’m being honored, she realized. Royalty didn’t stoop to using just anyone as a walking frame.


How can one feel something material ("knuckles") in an empty object ("glove clutch")?
"as a walking frame" hints Angelin used Miriam as support, I'm trying to imagine how they walked together. What the phrase about knuckles tell about that?

I'm confused. Is "empty" means w/out gloves? If so, who put a hand in the clutch - Angelin or Miriam?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Literature SE not English Language and Usage. The OP is asking for an explanation of a passage in the text, which requires understanding of what is happening in the story, the characters, the situation, etc, and knowledge of appropriate/common behaviour at the time the story is set, rather than knowledge of specific details of English language and usage. There's nothing linguistic or grammatical about an empty glove with walnuts placed in it.

@StuartF, "There's nothing linguistic" - the meaning of the word "empty"? Is it not?

What exactly is a glove clutch? Is it a small purse for gloves?

@Mitch, I thought so, however as one comment suggested clutch is a verb here. And I consider it a reasonable explanation. What is still not clear to me is meaning of "empty" word in English.

@Martian2020 ok I think I got it. Yes it's a hard sentence to parse: Angelina is clutching at Miriam's arm. Miriam is feeling Angelin clutch at Miriam's arm, or feeling Angelin's knuckles clutch at Miriam's arm. What kind of knuckles? Those that are like walnuts in an empty leather glove. Presumably empty but for those walnuts (her hand is so bony and fleshless. Yeah I find the metaphor kind of a stretch and that impedes understanding of the rest.

If a container is empty, it can either mean that there is nothing in the container, or that there is nothing else in the container. For example, Google finds several instances of the sentence:

I was all alone in an empty house.

If the house were literally empty, you couldn't be in it.
Similarly for the phrase

some cats like to sleep in empty boxes.

If the boxes were literally empty, there couldn't be cats sleeping in them.
So in this sentence, what the author most probably meant was that the glove feels like it doesn't contain anything except walnuts. (Of course, the "walnuts" are actually Angelin's knuckles in the glove.)
Clutch here is a verb, and a "walking frame" is the object that Americans usually call a "walker"—an object with four legs and a handle that you can use for support when walking. Angelin is simply holding onto Miriam's arm with her gloved hand for support—this is what being used as a "walking frame" means here.

In my reading, there’s no glove; it’s just her hand.

@Xanne, maybe, however from my knowledge of "Royalty", they tend to wear gloves [at receptions] - though that is was at a reception I have not included in the citation.
